# Adding a right click menu option when highlighting text

Tags: registry, shortcut, right-click

When i highlight a certain text, I would like to add a menu option

For Eg:
If I highlight a certain text it should append that text to a URL and open it in a browser.

i.e. If i highlight gizmo, there should be a right click menu option 'Open in youtube' and the browser should go to 
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gizmo

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to Chrome browser extensions, consider trying:

Simple = Select + Search

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-select-+-search/aagminaekdpcfimcbhknlgjmpnnnmooo?utm_source=gmail

I was able to customize this for local DBs I use. Very convenient.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this can append the URL, or place it anywhere within the URL.